# Eclipse plug in 'Find Bar for Eclipse' not available anymore?

Tags: eclipse, plugins, find

I want to install the 'Find Bar for Eclipse' plug in from the market place https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/find-bar-eclipse. I like this plugin and I used it a lot before. So, when I just started to work in a new company, I want to use it again.

However, it seems that it is not available anymore. This is the situation: when I was trying to install this plug in on Eclipse Neon. It shows that the repository site is not accessible.

I knew that we can import (and manually copy related .jar files) from another machine. However, I cannot have access to my old PC any longer (since it was in the previous company.)

My questions are:
(1) Any other repository to install this plug in?
(2) if not, anyone can share your plugin to me? (collect those .jar, preference files. zip it and send to me?)

Thanks.

Comment: The marketplace seems to be [down](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/) at the moment, maybe that is the problem.

Comment: Yes, it is. However, I want to get this plug in from someone has it installed. So he/she can zip the related .jar files and share to me. do you have this?